# How to use tf.data.Options()?

Tags: tensorflow-datasets

Is one dataset created accompanied by default options? If not, how to use the tf.data.Options()? Just dataset = dataset.with_options(options)? Is there anything else to be noticed?

Answer (score 4):

First create a tf.data.options instance. Then set the properties as you wish. For example:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(10000)

options = tf.data.Options()
options.experimental_optimization.apply_default_optimizations = True
options.experimental_threading.private_threadpool_size = 10

dataset = dataset.with_options(options)
```

[For all options available to you](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Options)